# What is the full code name of this electronic device?

Tags: identification

What is the full code name of this electronic device?
This is an electronic device on the mainboard of a Samsung laptop. 
Only "6GT" is written on the surface.

The ball pen is visible at the bottom side on pictures.. it is small size.

Length 2mm Width 2mm side device

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

Comment: Do you have any idea what it's doing? That might help track it down

Comment: If you could give an additional pic a bit zoomed out with surrounding components, we might be able to figure out what it does. The thick traces suggest supply or ground planes, but it's not easy to tell what this circuit is doing. I'm guessing this is something along the lines of a BC818 NPN transistor based on the 6G marking.

Answer (score 2):

With a lot of luck someone would know what vendor uses these markings.

In all likelihood, nobody will.

We'd need more context to confirm, but considering the thick traces around this: Probably a switch-mode power supply controller.

Your picture isn't good enough, we can't tell whether this is 6-DFN, or BGA, and there's no absolute size reference, so your best chance is searching through [catalogs of 6-contact-packages](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-voltage-regulators-dc-dc-switching-regulators/739?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv16=389546&pv16=267347&pv16=267405&pv16=267407&pv16=267412&pv16=267413&pv16=267415&pv16=267416&pv16=267417&pv16=267418&pv16=267607&pv16=267613&pv16=267614&pv16=267662&pv16=267669&pv16=267674&pv16=267676&pv16=267677&pv16=267678&pv16=267679&pv16=267792&pv16=267795&pv16=267796&pv16=267798&pv16=267800&pv16=267802&pv16=267804&pv16=267805&sf=1&FV=-8%7C739%2C69%7C409393%2C69%7C409401&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25) and hope it's one of these.

Regarding the thing you're probably asking this for: if this component is broken, so is probably a flyback diode somewhere, or an external switch semiconductor. Repair will be hard without an actual schematic.

In fact, [here's](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-voltage-regulators-dc-dc-switching-regulators/739?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv1291=254898&pv1291=266537&pv1291=266565&pv1291=266755&pv1291=267228&pv1291=267360&pv1291=267402&pv1291=267427&pv1291=267435&pv1291=267666&pv1291=267761&pv1291=266904&sf=1&FV=69%7C409393%2C69%7C409401%2C-8%7C739%2C16%7C267347%2C16%7C267405%2C16%7C267407%2C16%7C267412%2C16%7C267413%2C16%7C267415%2C16%7C267416%2C16%7C267417%2C16%7C267418%2C16%7C267607%2C16%7C267613%2C16%7C267614%2C16%7C267662%2C16%7C267669%2C16%7C267674%2C16%7C267676%2C16%7C267677%2C16%7C267678%2C16%7C267679%2C16%7C267792%2C16%7C267795%2C16%7C267796%2C16%7C267798%2C16%7C267800%2C16%7C267802%2C16%7C267804%2C16%7C267805%2C16%7C389546&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25) a list of 2×2mm packages that fit your description. I don't think it's just a transistor package.

Comment: Thank you for answer..The ball pen is visible at the bottom side on pictures.. it is small size.

Comment: "small size" is not something I can translate to millimeters.

Comment: I added the size data. :)

Comment: excellent, that makes it easier for you to go through that list.

Comment: yes, i see. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The closest matching part I found was [PEMB20](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PEMB20_PUMB20.pdf), a general-purpose dual package PNP transistor. It does have a 6G marking code. It's available in a various packages SOT363 or SOT666, which might be what we see on the picture.

Comment: Thank vert much for your answer. I guess this is a transistor too. I let's find what you said. Thank you.

Comment: And i added zoom out picture.

Comment: @sungkim Yep, looks like some power distribution circuitry to various parts of the board. I'm guessing all those surrounding parts below it are BJT or MOSFET. Guessing wildly, the BJTs around the tweezers could be something like an interface/polarity fix between one of the SoC parts and MOSFETs, if the MOSFET can't be controlled directly from pin logic voltage levels.

Comment: it is Length 2mm Width 2mm side device side.thanks :)

Comment: When power is applied, 18v enters one pin of that electronic device. And it gets hot.